# How to write a C# unit test in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

This is my first unit test and wanted some help clearing out my thoughts about the process of writing a unit test.

I wanted to write a test method that will add a new user - using my AddUser method in my library class.

```
Document doc = new Document();

[TestMethod]
public string AddUser()
{
    string name = doc.AddUser("Testing User");
    Assert.IsNotNull(name);
}
```

The error I am getting on build:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `string`

This is my `AddUser` method:

```
public void AddUser(string newUserName)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            FullName = newUserName,
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, do you understand the error message? Where did you expect the value of `name` to come from in your test?

Comment: Also, this is less of a unit test and more of an integration test. Essentially, you're testing `DataContext`. I'd recommend against unit testing outside of the scope of your own code. Test your implementaton details and try to steer away from integration tests masking as unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you return the name from from your `AddUser(string newUserName)` method.

Replace your method like

```
public String AddUser(string newUserName)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            FullName = newUserName,
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    return newUserName;
}
```

Comment: THanks this worked great and built. But now when i run the test to see how it will work it get a failed test- `system.nullreferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 12):

Your method does not have a return value:

```
public void AddUser
       ^^^^ no return value
```

So you can't store it into a string:

```
string name = doc.AddUser("Testing User");
^^^^^^^^^^^ AddUser has no return value
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddUser` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

`AddUser` is written as a method, not a class.  Your test attempts to call it like a method, but the method is void, which does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking you can't assign void to string.

To make it work you can do in 2 ways:
make your method `AddUser` `return` `string` type or add extra `parameter` to your `method` and use `keyword` `out` for this `parameter`

hope it help.